# Identify data warehouse design methodologies in the following diagram

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, hybrid, bottom-up, top-down

Can someone help me identify the top-down, bottom-up, and hybrid data warehouse design methodologies as mentioned [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse#Design_methodologies) in the following diagram? I am interested in understanding how the diagram differs depending on each design methodology.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is too generic to enable identification of a methodology. Further, the Wikipedia article is surprisingly out of date.

There are four mainstream DW methodologies in common use today - Dimensional (Kimball), 3NF (Inmon), Data Vault (Linstedt) and Anchor Modelling (Ronnback). All could be represented within that diagram.

The issue of top-down or bottom-up in this article is centred around data marts. There is no requirement that marts are stored in a separate database, or even in a DBMS. In the context of your diagram they might exist in either the data warehouse or the analysis tool. In any case, the diagram does not give any indication of what came first, so you can't infer an approach.

In order to identify the methodology (Kimball, etc.) that was used to design the warehouse you'd need to see its data model. It would be immediately apparent from the model.

To identify the order in which components were delivered you'd need to see some sort of timeline, project plan, etc.